# Triggers when a field isn't included

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working on a MySQL database and I haven't done too much with triggers before, but found a specific scenario where I am using them. I am running into something odd though. In short, my trigger isn't effecting a certain field, unless it's specified. I'm hoping someone can correct that so that it is always effected.

Here's the sample code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reservations;
CREATE TABLE reservations(
    resid int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    siteid int(5),
    camperid int(8),
    charge decimal(10,2),
    checkin datetime NOT NULL,
    checkout datetime NOT NULL,
    balance decimal(10,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (resid),
    FOREIGN KEY (siteid) REFERENCES sites(siteid),
    FOREIGN KEY (camperid) REFERENCES campers(camperid)
);
```

now the trigger

```
DELIMETER //
CREATE TRIGGER balanceCheck BEFORE INSERT ON reservations 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   IF NEW.balance != NEW.charge THEN SET NEW.balance = NEW.charge; END IF; 
END;// --this isn't working yet
DELIMETER;
```

Here's the SQL that the trigger does not catch

```
INSERT INTO reservations (resid, siteid, camperid, charge, checkin, checkout)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 90, '2016-04-10 13:00:00', '2016-04-12 15:00:00');
```

Here's the SQL that the trigger does catch

```
INSERT INTO reservations (resid, siteid, camperid, charge, checkin, checkout, balance) 
VALUES (2, 1, 1, 90, '2016-04-10 13:00:00', '2016-04-12 15:00:00', 9);
```

Seems to depend on if I reference the effected field or not on if the trigger can effect it. How can I make it so that the balance field is always effected, even if it isn't specified? I'd like to keep this solution using a trigger if possible.

Comment: Set default values for `charge` and `balance`

Answer (score 1):

Because `new.balance` is `NULL` for the first `INSERT`, `NEW.balance != NEW.charge` isn't true. Equality or inequality operations on `NULL`s come out as `NULL`, which is not true, so in other words false. That follows, that the `THEN` branch of the `IF` isn't entered.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> (...)
>
> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` to test for `NULL`.
>
> (...)
>
> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` is also `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.
>   In MySQL, 0 or NULL means false and anything else means true.
>
> (...)

But in MySQL you can use the `NULL`-safe equal operator [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```
CREATE TRIGGER balanceCheck
               BEFORE INSERT
               ON reservations
               FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT NEW.balance <=> NEW.charge THEN
    SET NEW.balance = NEW.charge;
  END IF;
END;
```